# How compare a char / single char string - with some list of alphabets set

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

in my app i have to display different color for different Names depends on Starting letter

```
abcdeABCDE - gray color
:
:
pqrsPQRS - red Color
vuwxyzUVWXYZ - black color.
```

I have implemented like this..

This gives correct result as i want, But this is not an optimal solution

is there any simple solution to do this

```
NSString *FirstLetter = [empName substringFromIndex:1];

if ( [FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"p"] || [FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"q"] || [FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"r"] || [FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"=s"] || [FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"P"] || [FirstLetterisEqualToString:@"Q"] || [FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"R"] || [FirstLetter isEqualToString:@"S"])
    {
        cell.textalbel.textColr =[UIColor redColor]; 
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of ways to implement this, but the simplest is probably just this:

```
static UIColor *colorForFirstLetterOfString(NSString *string) {
    unichar c = [[[string substringToIndex:1] lowercaseString] characterAtIndex:0];
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'e') return [UIColor grayColor];
    // ...
    else if (c >= 'p' && c <= 's') return [UIColor redColor];
    else if (c >= 'u' && c <= 'z') return [UIColor blackColor];
    else return nil;
}
```

Should you need to go outside the ASCII character set, you can use numeric constants for Unicode code points, like this:

```
// lower-case Greek letters
else if (c >= 0x03B1 && c <= 0x03C9) return [UIColor blueColor];
```

or you can use an `L` prefix on your character constants, like this:

```
// lower-case Greek letters
else if (c >= L'α' && c <= L'ω') return [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: Why is everyone returning colors when OP wants color names (strings)?

Comment: The code in his post sets `cell.textLabel.textColor` to `[UIColor redColor]` when `FirstLetter` is in the range `p…s`.  (Well, it would do that if the typos were fixed. ☺)  So it seems to me he's asking for color objects, not strings.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. (How much I hate poorly phrased questions...!)

Answer (score 4):

If the starting letter is always an English character (or anything representable by a reasonably small integer that fits into an `unsigned char`), then here's a solution (the fastest possible one I can think of - uses no jumps except for the first check for initialization and only plain old integers are used instead of the somewhat heavier-weight comparison of `NSString` instances):

```
- (UIColor *)colorFromName:(NSString *)name
{
    static UIColor *strs[1 << CHAR_BIT] = { nil };
    static BOOL initted = NO;

    if (!initted) {
        strs['a'] = [UIColor greyColor];
        strs['b'] = [UIColor whiteColor];
        // ...
        strs['z'] = [UIColor blueColor];

        initted = YES;
    }

    unsigned char first = tolower([name characterAtIndex:0]);
    return strs[first];
}
```

Comment: The downvote was for the 256 element array (assuming 8 bit CHAR_BIT). That's hardly *optimal* (from a memory utilization point-of-view).

Comment: And anyway, it's not just 1kB: You're forgetting to add the memory of 26 UIColor objects, when 5 or 6 would have sufficed.

Comment: @rein Or do you honestly think that a new `UIColor` object is created upon each call to `+ [UIColor XXXColor]`? Because it's not the case, those are singletons.

Comment: @rein Furthermore, nobody prohibits multiple assignment, in case one writes `arr['a'] = arr['b'] = [UIColor whiteColor];`, even the cost of multiple function calls is avoided (but that's irrelevant anyway since the initialization occurs only once during the lifetime of the program). All in all, your argument is invalid.

Comment: Yes, you're correct about the singletons if the named colors are used.

Comment: I don't understand why my comment was removed, so here it is again for future visitors: the 256-element array occupies only 1kB of memory (since the size of a C pointer is 4 bytes on iOS). RAM is far less expensive than CPU cycles; if this method needs to be optimized, the only reason I can think of is that it's called a lot continuously, so it needs to be fast. And this jump-less approach is definitely faster than the ones with nested ifs and dictionary lookups.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary for this. Something similar to the following:

```
NSString *empName = @"Henry";
UIColor *color = nil;
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      [UIColor redColor], @"abcde",
                      [UIColor blueColor], @"fghij",
                      nil];
NSString *firstLetter = [empName substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
for (NSString *key in dict.keyEnumerator) {
    if ([key rangeOfString:firstLetter options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
        color = [dict objectForKey:key];
        break;
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", color);
```

Comment: This solution isn't any more "optimal" (faster) than the original one.

Comment: The definition of optimal in this case was simpler, not faster.

Comment: 1. How do you know? 2. Then why are you downvoting my answer? It's even simpler.

Comment: I didn't downvote anyone, but the question does say this: “is there any simple solution to do this”  Certainly “optimal” and “simple” are often mutually exclusive.

Comment: Well, "optimal" is subjective since it means "Best or most favorable". Best for what? Memory / speed / readability? "Simpler" is far les subjective so I went with that, seeing as the repetitive logical conditions in the original question seemed to be the OP's pain point.

Comment: @rein Yet he accepted Rob mayoff's answer... with repetitive `if`s inside. A plain C array subscription is definitely a better choice both in terms of readability and performance.

Comment: @robmayoff Not in this case - a simple C array subscription is bth faster and easier to read than dictionaries, nested ifs, whatever.